# C#.NET send email based on two conditions

Tags: c#, .net, linq, visual-studio

I have the following code segment that sends an email to users based on 'RequestApproval' being set to true on their records in a SQL table - it works perfectly.

```
        SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient();

        List<SigList> LST_SigList = LK_CRFData.SigLists.Where(x => x.RequestApproval == true).ToList();
        string URL = sponsorURL + OB_CRF.id;

        foreach (SigList OB_SigList in LST_SigList)
        {
            string Name = OB_SigList.UserName.Trim();
            Name = Name.Substring(0, Name.IndexOf("."));
            Name = Name[0].ToString().ToUpper() + Name.Substring(1, Name.Length - 1);

            MailMessage myMessage = new MailMessage("SponsorApproved@nhs.net", OB_SigList.EmailAddress);
            myMessage.Subject = "Sponsor has approved the request on the " + TB_DateTimeofImplementationStart.Text.Substring(0, 10) + " for \"" + TB_CNNO.Text + " " + TB_Title.Text + "\"";
            myMessage.Body = "Dear " + Name + ", \n\nThe sponsor has now approved CN NO : " + TB_CNNO.Text + "\nTitle      : " + TB_Title.Text + "\nImplementation Date : " + TB_DateTimeofImplementationStart.Text.Substring(0, 10) + "\n\nClick the link to open the document:\n" + URL;
            mySmtpClient.Send(myMessage);
            }
```

However, for certain functions, I want to send the email where 'Request approval is set to True OR False. I've ammended it to the following to no avail:

```
List<SigList> LST_SigList = LK_CRFData.SigLists.Where(x => x.RequestApproval == true || x.RequestApproval == false).ToList();
```

It still sends emails out the old way -only to those who have Request Approval' set to true.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What wrong with the linq

Comment: this `List<SigList> LST_SigList = LK_CRFData.SigLists.Where(x => x.RequestApproval == true || x.RequestApproval == false).ToList();` get which contain both true and false. Please check you input data for any false case

Comment: Hi, thanks for feedback. If i understand what you mean, I can confirm that the table does have some records which have RequestApproval set to false.

Comment: Assuming RequestApproval is not a nullable type, wouldn't you just omit the Where clause altogether? `List<SigList> LST_SigList = LK_CRFData.SigLists.ToList();`

Comment: If RequestApproval is a nullable bool (bool?) then testing for false would fail... if you don't care for true or false you could just remove the .Where condition...

Comment: Hi, Thanks to you both - i have tried that and for some reason its still only sending the email where people are = true....

Comment: You should then check how `LK_CRFData.SigLists` is populated from the source. Ensure it has both true and false values prior to the Linq query. In my example above there is no filtering of the data whatsoever.

Comment: If `RequestApproval` is non-nullable, couldn't you just remove the `Where` clause altogether...?

Comment: Your error is not in the code that you provided.  Make sure you are actually calling the modified method, and not the original one or something similar.  As this isn't a LINQ problem, and you haven't provided enough code to replicate, I'm calling for this question to be closed.

Comment: Hello Robert, thanks for the reply. There is no error - as explained in my question, the code still sends out emails the old way, only to those who have 'RequestApproval' set to true. I have provided the entire method that is being called. No worries, I will continue to explore this myself. Thanks.